# Visual Studio .msi running as 32 bit instead of 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio, installation, 64-bit, windows-installer

I am using visual studio to generate an installer for my project. I am compiling the solution as Any CPU and I have the targeted platform in the installer set to x64. The problem is that when I run the installer, it runs as x86, not x64. This is a problem because I am using Add-In express that requires the code to be executable at install time and I access the 64 bit registry in my project. As a result, the program installs successfully but only after it throws about 10 errors due to looking for the registry key in WOW6432Node rather than the standard 64 bit directory.

How can I make the installer run as 64 bit rather than 32 bit or is this not possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Something doesn't add up in this question.  Whether your project runs in 32-bit or 64-bit mode after it is installed doesn't have anything to do with the bitness of the installer.  If the installer puts your EXE in c:\program files instead of c:\program files (x86) then it is good.  Your program runs in 64-bit mode after it is installed when the EXE project targets AnyCPU and the 64-bit version of the framework is installed and enabled.

Comment: I realize that it has nothing to do with the bitness of the installer. What I am referring to is a problem that occurs specifically with the product Add-in Express. I generate no .exe, I generate a DLL which is then activated using an .exe of theirs (specifically adxregistrator.exe). I apologize for being vague in this mechanic but I don't fully understand the behind the scenes operations. Now that I have had time to think about it further, I suspect the problem is that their .exe runs emulated as 32 bit even though my .msi targets 64 bit explicitly and I am pursuing that suspicion.

Comment: What on Earth is "Add-in Express"?  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: @ThomasRobinson Do you use custom actions for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio always generates x86 compatible setup project. To access the WOW6432Node key you need to create a custom action application (.exe file built for ANYCPU) and add it to the Custom Action Editor of the setup project. In this case your code will run as x64 app on x64 platforms by default.